# React Native ref child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, ecmascript-6

I have a custom InputText (from React Native Paper) component, and in its parent I wanna have access to its focus() method.

Actually I am using useRef hook in the parent but not getting all props of the child, only all which I defined in the component.

```
// Parent: 
...
import TextInput from "../components/TextInput";
...
const titleInput = useRef();
...
<TextInput
     ref={titleInput}
     placeholder="Write a title"
     multiline
     counter
/>
...



// Child:
...
import { TextInput as RNPTextInput, withTheme } from "react-native-paper";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

render() {
  ...
  return (
    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <RNPTextInput
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={text}
        multiline={multiline}
        maxLength={maxLength}
        maxHeight={56}
        dense
        autoCorrect={false}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        selectionColor={colors.primary}
        onChangeText={this.handleChangeText}
        style={styles.input}
      />
      {counter && (
        <Text style={[styles.charactersCounter, { color: colors.gray }]}>
          {`${text.length}/${maxLength}`}
        </Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Anyways, if I don't use the custom component and just use the original component (imported in the parent from react-native-paper), I have access to all props.

Do you know how to get *all* props of a child?

Comment: You wanted to access the ref of the parent ?

Comment: Nope. In my custom component I have imported a component from other library, which have an specific method I want to use in the parent. The problem is that if in the parent I reference my custom child component, I only see the props I specified, and not the ones that are defined in the library... Anyways I have solved it referencing the original component on my custom child, and then (when component mounts) pass the ref to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

As its a controlled element I believe you don't want to change anything from the parent.

- If you want to get notified when the control got focused then use callback function from the child.

Parent

```
 function onFocusParentCallBack {
           ........
     }
   - <Child notifyParent={onFocusParentCallBack } />
```

Child

```
 function onFocus(e) {
      const { notifyParent } = props;
      if (notifyParent) { 
        notifyParent(e);
       }
    }
   <Input onFoucus={onFocus} />
```